# Airlock has a bug inside

Tags: airlock

My airlock today has a bug inside, I think it must have crawled in and died from an overdose of cheap Gin. Anyway, I was wondering, should I wait to clean out the airlock until I move to secondary or is it safe to remove it now, clean it and pop it back in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking it is safer to remove, clean/sterilise and replace the airlock. It should only take 30 seconds and the vent hole can be covered with an inverted glass to prevent any accidental ingress. If you have a spare airlock (they are cheap enough) then you can prepare and replace the offending item almost instantly.

One could *possibly* leave the bug in the airlock and it *probably* will not cause any problems after all there should be little "suction" on the airlock to cause a reverse flow. But be careful when removing the lid, bung or the air lock itself because this is the time when "suck-back" may happen.